# Updating Angular.json file

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ng2-bootstrap

I was using ng2-bootstrap (from my package.json file). Since it was deprecated, I replaced it with ngx-bootstrap. When trying to build I get the below error because angular.json still is looking for the file "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/node_modules/moment/moment.js"

I've attempted:

```
"npm install -g @angular/cli"
"npm install @angular/cli"
"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli"
"npm install --save @angular/cli"
"npm install"
"ng update @angular/cli"
```

but none of these actually update the angular.json file

Error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/..../node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/node_modules/moment/moment.js'
```

Comment: You could always manually edit the file?

Comment: Looking at your attempts, you are re-installing the Angular CLI, and updating it to the newest version. This will *not* change any of your unique included packages (such as ng2-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap). You would need to specifically uninstall the one and install the other. Or it may be easier to just manually update the angular.json file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am aware I can manually edit angular.json but for future purposes I was wondering how these packages in angular.json are generated/changed.

Comment: angular.json file is never modified on npm changes, only package.json file is

Comment: @benshabatnoam That's been clarified, then how do you modify angular.json file (non-manually)?

Comment: "When trying to build I get the below error" where is it?

Comment: @benshabatnoam sorry about that, I just edited it with the error message basically showing that it's looking for  ng2-bootstrap (which I removed from package.json)

Comment: These packages are not generated in `angular.json`. Very few can and it's specified in their docs. Moreover, I don't understand what the problem lies under 1 string so that you can't do it manually.

Comment: Ok, my question is simply how do I update (non manually) the angular.json file?